# Tramp: Is there a way to use something like ssh-directory-tracking-mode but via ssh instead of ftp?

Tags: tramp, ssh

The boxes I'm working with are locked down and only have the SSH port (22) open, so I can't use directory tracking via FTP. But directory tracking is really handy.

There has to be a way. Does anyone know of a method or library that will do `dirtrack-mode` via SSH?

Comment: I've never used `shell` over TRAMP (as it's of little use for me, I just prefer to use a proper terminal outside of Emacs). Have you tried starting `shell` from a buffer that's pointing to a remote file? I recall the `!` command in `dired` doing the right thing and executing commands on the remote machine.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get it to at least set the `default-directory` on login by adding this: `(setq default-directory (concat "/ssh:" ssh-remote-user "@" ssh-host ":~"))` to my custom wrapper arround the `ssh` command. But it doesn't update when I change directories. This is much better than nothing, I'm just surprised this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is `shell-dirtrack-mode` which is said to work also on remote shell buffers via Tramp.